# Calculating P values for given t value in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

Ques: What is the p-value for the two-tail test(assuming 5% confidence interval) of the hypothesis that the equation intercept is zero?

I have calculated the t value(1.257) for a data set with 51 observations in a linear regression model. Its Degree of freedom is 49.Now how can I calculate the p value based on the above information in R?

Comment: In order to improve the quality of your question, it is better to prepare a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think the information is sufficient to calculate the p value ...

Comment: there is no need of data set as i have mentioned the degree of freedom in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the cumulative distribution function `pt`.

```
t <- 1.257
df <- 49
2 * (1 - pt(q = abs(t), df = df))
[1] 0.2147125
```

or alternatively:

```
2 * pt(q = abs(t), df = df, lower=FALSE)
```